# How do I disable specific mods?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-technic-pack

I've been mucking around with the Technic pack and I want to try to play game with only Mystcraft. I don't want to be bothered by managing/avoiding Taint from Thaumcraft nor do I want the multitude of chests I find in cave worlds to be cluttered by items from other mods.

I know that I can "disable" some mods by deleting them wholesale from the mods folder, but I'd like the ability to enable at a later time. I realize that there is a "Mod Select" button in the Technic Launcher but that button has been grey since my nana's 13th birthday so I don't expect any help in that direction.

Comment: or disable a mod by adding ".disabled" after the jar/zip file of the mod (it's how FTB does it)

Comment: Or, instead of using Technic, just install Mystcraft...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ability to disable mods has been removed from Technic Pack, which is why the button is greyed out. (I wanted to turn off a bunch of them when I was playing, and found that I couldn't after some research.) http://questions.technicpack.net/24/how-do-i-disable-certain-mods-from-a-pack has some info on it, but again, they say that the feature's been removed.

Considering Mystcraft is 1.4.6 compatible, your best bet is probably just to install that mod directly into a clean minecraft.jar file.

Mystcraft: http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/918541-146-mystcraft-09500/
Forge (required by Mystcraft to load the mod): http://www.minecraftforge.net/forum/

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you after answering about the removal of the ability to disable certain mods in the Technic/Tekkit launcher.

Answer (score 0):

Just put the mods you want to use later in a folder on the desktop and then put them back later. You can do the same for forge.

Comment: Does no answer the question very good... Try taking a bit more time to write an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Copy the world you are using from tekkit/technic to vanilla.
Then install mystcraft, and you should have all your stuff from mystcraft, and non from the other mods.

**How to find your tekkit/technic world** (only works for windows)
1. Click the windows icon in the left bottom corner.
2. Type in: Run (only if you have english windows. Else type run in your own languge).
3. Then you should get a little box. Type in: %appdata%
4. Now click the folder: .Techniclaucher
5. Now you should see all the diffrent modpacks, technic includes. (if some of them is missing its because you havn't played them). Click technic or tekkit, depents on what modpack you play with.
6. Now click saves, and you should see all your worlds. Just drag the one you want, into vanilla minecraft. (In the save folder).

**How to find vanilla minecraft saves** (where you have to drag you tekkit/technic world to)
1. Click the windows icon in the left bottom corner.
2. Type in: Run (only if you have english windows. Else type run in your own languge).
3. Then you should get a little box. Type in: %appdata%
4. Click .Minecraft
5. Click saves, and drag you Tekkit/Technic world into there, and install Mystcraft and  you are good to go :D

Comment: This feels like it could be risky in case I have non-Mystcraft blocks placed (Crucibles come to mind).

Comment: i've done it multiple times and nothing went wrong. the blocks that aren't mystcraft blocks will just disappear

Comment: You can always kam a backup of everything and try it... Then if it dosn't work then just restore the backup.